# Why did this apple explode?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, home-experiment

In this [video](http://youtu.be/-7--fzZE2qk?t=495), the apple suddenly explodes when it goes off balance and isn't touching anything. Anyone knows any possible reasons?

Comment: The apple is rotating and it has a metal axis passing through it. This causes stress on the apple and the structure fails to hold. Hence, it breaks.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained - currently it is unclear what you are asking without watching a video. If the link to the video rots away (e.g. the uploader deletes it), the question will become completely incomprehensible for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've been double clicking it to look frame-by-frame (poor little mouse).

1) the skin no longer provides any structural integrity as it is removed
2) as the peeler gets to the end it starts to push the apple off the "fork"
3) the furthest point of the apple from the "fork" begins to fall due to gravity
4) the force of gravity trying to change the rotational axis introduces new stress into the apple.
5) The apple initially splits in half, then fragments into more pieces. The plane of each division intersects the axis of rotation (more or less).

Suggested inprovement: mount the peeler vertically upwards.